# Execute IF-THEN_ELSE before Execute Calculation - Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, sumifs, calculated-field, level-of-detail

I have a graph below.

[image]

I would like to calculate lapsed rate which is sum of lapsed value divided by sum of inforce value. I use the formula below in calculated field.

```
abs(sum(if[Status]='lapsed'then[TotalAmount]end))/abs(sum(if[Status]='inforce'then[TotalAmount]end))
```

However that formula will also pick the value from Q2 (quarter 2) 2016. What I want to do is to tell tableau to check first if any quarter does not contain both inforce value and lapsed value then skip that quarter. In this case I need to calculate lapsed rate which does not include Q2 2016. How do i do this?

I'm using Tableau v.10.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a quick approach and may not be the most efficient but it seems to work.

You need to use a combination of a row level calculation and a level of detail calculation. 
The level of detail calculation can be used to flag the quarters which have both a lapsed and inforced status. Once these quarters are flagged you can calculate the lapsed rate at a row level which can then be rolled up using a sum.

Create a calculated field as follows: 
Let me know if you have any questions or need any tweaks.

```
 if
avg(
// Calculate the number of Inforce/Lapsed occurences per Quarter
IF 
[Status] = 'Inforce'
or 
[Status] = 'Lapsed'
then 
{ FIXED 
DATEPART('quarter', [Date]):
countd([Status])
}
else 
0
end)
//
= 2
then 
// Calculate the Lapsed Rate as both statuses exist in the quarter
sum((if 
[Status] = 'Lapsed'
then [Total Amount]
END))
/ 
sum([Total Amount])


END
```